# Extjs4 localstorage -- How to Remove All records?

Tags: local-storage, extjs4.1

The Local Storage proxy seems to be rather buggy in Extjs 4.1.  Please tell me I'm doing something wrong.

I'm attempting (like others) to load data from the server then store it locally for offline use.  My problem involves refreshing the data (hitting reload in the browser).  `removeAll()` doesn't remove any records.  I've read that you can clear local storage out by calling `clear()` on the local storage proxy itself. While the records are removed, the key generator isn't reset.  I'm concerned this will eventually cause a problem.

In my code, what am I doing that would cause LocalStorage to misbehave?  I know there is some trickiness with the setting id's correctly on the model, but I think I'm doing that correctly.

Here's the model and store:

```
            Ext.define('MAP.model.LookupData', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

                idProperty:'localId',

                fields: [
                    'localId', // used for storing data via a localstorage proxy. -jg
                    'name',
                    'value'
                ]
            });


            Ext.define('MAP.store.LocalCloudConditionStore', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
                model: 'MAP.model.LookupData',
                storeId: 'localCloudConditionStore',

                proxy: {
                    type: 'localstorage',
                    id  : 'cloud-conditions'
                }

            });
```

Here's code attempting to use `removeAll()` to clear the local store:

```
    offlineStore.load();
    offlineStore.removeAll();
    offlineStore.sync();

    Ext.each(records,function(record){
        var added = offlineStore.add(record.getData())[0];
        console.log(added.get('id'));
    });

    offlineStore.sync();
```

What the local storage proxy writes to my browser:

[image: First load]

And the Second reload does. it doesn't remove the prior ones:

[image: Second load. Frist load data isn't removed.]

If I try using `proxy.clear()`, records go away, but the idGenerator seed isn't reset:

```
    offline.getProxy().clear();

    Ext.data.StoreManager.register(offline);

    Ext.each(records,function(record){
        var added = offline.add(record.getData())[0];
        console.log(added.get('id'));
    });

    offline.sync();
```

[image: the counter isn't reset!]

Thanks for your eyeballs.

**UPDATE**

I've been able to reset the local storage's counter by directly reseting the value before instantiating my localstore.  Obviously, this goes off the reservation, so it isn't ideal.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('cloud-conditions-counter',0);

var offline = Ext.create('MAP.store.LocalCloudConditionStore');

offline.getProxy().clear();
```

**UPDATE DEUX**

Upon further reflection, I think it's correct to not reset the counter.  When a table in mysql is truncated, you don't reset the sequence number.  That could cause problems if some cached id of a deleted record (let's say id of 1) was used to pull data from the table.  A totally different record would be returned instead of the one that was deleted.  Okay, makes sense.

Still, why the heck doesn't `store.removeAll(); store.sync()` work?

Comment: When a table in an SQL database is truncated, the engine reset the sequence id, if you delete the records without use TRUNCATE statement then you don't reset the sequence. I have the same issue, my concern is because the store doesn't reset the counter. Any way if you call store.count(), the right value is returned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is a bug, but I am sure that `removeAll()` does not mark the records as deleted and will not affect remote or local storage (ie, a following sync won't do anything). This is in contrast to `remove()` - which actually does so.

You can use this method to remove all records:

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.Store), { 

    removeAllForReal: function() {
        records = this.data.items,
        i = records.length;

        while (i--) {
            this.remove( records[i] );
        }
    }
});
```